# Parameter entities in internal DTD

Tags: xml, dtd

I have the following `simple.dtd`:

```
<!ENTITY % placeholder "my, element, list">
<!ELEMENT root (%placeholder;)>
<!ELEMENT my (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT element (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT list (#PCDATA)>
```

and the `simple.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE root SYSTEM "simple.dtd">

<root>
    <my />
    <element />
    <list />
</root>
```

This works and is valid.

But the exact same DTD inline:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE root [
        <!ENTITY % placeholder "my, element, list">
        <!ELEMENT root (%placeholder;)>
        <!ELEMENT my (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT element (#PCDATA)>
        <!ELEMENT list (#PCDATA)>
]>

<root>
    <my />
    <element />
    <list />
</root>
```

fails with the error:

```
$ xmllint --valid simple.xml
simple.xml:4: parser error : ContentDecl : Name or '(' expected
        <!ELEMENT root (%placeholder;)>
                        ^
simple.xml:4: parser error : expected '>'
        <!ELEMENT root (%placeholder;)>
                        ^
Entity: line 1: parser error : internal error: xmlParseInternalSubset: error detected in Markup declaration

 %placeholder; 
              ^
Entity: line 1: 
my, element, list
^
Entity: line 1: parser error : DOCTYPE improperly terminated
 %placeholder; 
              ^
Entity: line 1: 
my, element, list
^
Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found
 %placeholder; 
              ^
Entity: line 1: 
my, element, list
^
```

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the *internal subset* of DTD, references to parameter entities are not allowed  within markup declarations. You have to use an external DTD, i.e. the separate file. This is documented as a well-formedness constraint in the XML specification [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#wfc-PEinInternalSubset).

Comment: _In the internal subset of DTD, references to parameter entities are not allowed._ To clarify a little; parameter entity references can't occur within markup declarations, but they can occur at the same level as markup declarations.

Comment: @DanielHaley Yeah, fixed my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#wfc-PEinInternalSubset) states:

> In the internal DTD subset, parameter-entity references must not occur
>   within markup declarations; they may occur where markup declarations
>   can occur. (This does not apply to references that occur in external
>   parameter entities or to the external subset.)

So in the internal subset, you can't reference the parameter entity from within a markup declaration.

You *can* reference it from the same level as a markup declaration though.

That means you'd have to declare/reference the parameter entity like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE root [
    <!ENTITY % placeholder "<!ELEMENT root (my, element, list)>">
    %placeholder;
    <!ELEMENT my (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT element (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT list (#PCDATA)>
]>
<root>
    <my />
    <element />
    <list />
</root>
```